# Can Ansible deploy public SSH key asking password only once?

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys, ansible-2.x

I wonder how to copy my SSH public key to many hosts using Ansible.

First attempt:

```
ansible all -i inventory -m local_action -a "ssh-copy-id {{ inventory_hostname }}" --ask-pass
```

But I have the error **`The module local_action was not found in configured module paths`**.

Second attempt using a playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  become: no
  tasks:
  - local_action: command ssh-copy-id {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

Finally I have entered my password for each managed host:

```
ansible all -i inventory --list-hosts | while read h ; do ssh-copy-id "$h" ; done
```

**How to fill password only once while deploying public SSH key to many hosts?**

---

---

**EDIT:**   I have succeeded to copy my SSH public key to multiple remote hosts using the following playbook from the [Konstantin Suvorov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708604/938111).

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - authorized_key:
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

The field `user` should be mandatory according to the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) but it seems to work without. Therefore the above generic playbook may be used for any user when used with this command line:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory authorized_key.yml -u "$USER" -k
```

Comment: For me, the `user` variable was required. I have set it to `"{{ ansible_user_id }}"` to use the current user name, but it can be set to something else if desired.

Comment: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "missing required arguments: user"}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you use [authorized_key](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) module?

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - authorized_key:
        user: remote_user_name
        state: present
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '/local/path/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

and run playbook with `-u remote_user_name -k`

Comment: password? Supposingly this is the first time the Ansible master connects to the new remote hosts. Otherwise why  not ssh-id-copy <remote host>